# Which graph database is suitable for a social media project?

Tags: graph-databases, blazegraph, bigdata

I want to start a project based on a graph database. We are struggling with selecting a database. Our project is about social media sharing (more than media). Each user has a profile like on Facebook with some properties (city, friendship, following system, etc.). Each user can post videos, images, articles, sounds and some more types.

I saw the [DB-Engines Ranking of Graph DBMS](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking/graph+dbms), but one of my team members insists on working with Blazegraph.

Which database is suitable for having a fast, scalable, and searchable social media site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Titan (Distributed Graph Database)](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/)

It also exposes a web interface for you to easily search for chains, loops, and all sorts of patterns.

I used it to search for patterns on a massive social network and it performed very well.

The same guys that created Titan also created [TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/).

Comment: Did you have any experience on it? do you think is better than neo4j or blazegraph?
please provide more details and some references.

Comment: well that's why I wrote titan and not neo4j: it is the one that I used, and the one I know that performs well. If I wasn't already familiar with titan, I'd just try those in order: [graph dbms](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking/graph+dbms)